# Nuxt how can I redirect user to previous page from my error layout?

Tags: error-handling, nuxt.js

I'm working on error page. In layout directory I have `error.vue` and `error_layout.vue`.

Say I'm on Login page and an error occurs (Network error for example, I'm handling server and validation errors in login page). It shows my error page, but URL is not changed, it is: `mydomain.com/login`

The problem here is that I want to have correct URL for example `mydomain.com/error`

I want this because I want to be able to return user on previous page (in my case - `mydomain.com/login`), but refresh shows error page with wrong URL. I can't go back.

`$nuxt.$route` gives me login route.

UPDATE:

Here is how I handle server errors, this is my interceptor plugin:

```js
export default function ({ $axios, redirect, app, error: nuxtError }) {

  $axios.onError((error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      if (error.response.status === 423) {
        redirect({
          name: 'confirm-password',
          query: { redirect_to: app.router.currentRoute.name }
        })
      }
    } else {
      // Unknown error, for example Network Error
      // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
      nuxtError({
        statusCode: 503,
        message: error.message
      }) 
      return Promise.resolve(false)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error comes from the server, then you can catch the error, then redirect the client to `error` page. For example if you are using `axios` then something like this:

```js
await this.$axios.post('/login-url', userCreds)
    .catch(e => {
        this.$router.push({
           path: '/error'
        })
    })
```

Comment: No, it is not server error. I'm using interceptor plugin. Just updated my question with code. I'm using error context to show error page.